# How many bytes does the function need?

Tags: c

```
int main(){
   int i;
}
```

I did `$ebp-$esp` in gdb after calling the function and it gave me 4. But what about old `ebp`? Can I consider this function needs 8 bytes on the stack? 4 bytes for an `int` and 4 bytes for an old `ebp`.

note-  I built it by using  `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i386`

Comment: Look at it in a disassembler.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without full compiler details.

Comment: A decent question, but why do you want to know?

Comment: @DanFego why do you want to know why he wants to know?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Because often when people ask questions that end up having answers like "it's compiler dependent," they're trying to solve the wrong problem to begin with. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on how the compiler decides to optimize the function. Some optimizing compilers might build this function as something along the lines of "`main: ret`", causing it to use no stack space at all.

Comment: Save for the return address, right? (I think the return address is logically in the frame of the called function).

Comment: But on the stack do we consider it in the caller's frame and the callee's frame starts from pushing the old ebo?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're compiling without optimisations, you're not counting the old ebp, because esp gets copied to ebp after the old ebp is pushed on the stack. I think what you're seeing is gcc saving ecx although offhand I'm not sure why it does.

Answer (score 0):

How much memory that function requires is going to depend entirely upon the compiler you're using. This is the disassembly of the above code using gcc 4.6.2 with the compile command:

```
gcc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i386 -m32 -o test test.c

   0x08048394 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x08048395 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048397 <+3>: pop    ebp
   0x08048398 <+4>: ret
```

What's fairly obvious is that `i` is ignored, since it's not used at all. Therefore you have 4 bytes on the stack for the return address pushed by `call`, and another 4 for preserving `ebp`.

As you'd expect, if you enabled slight optimisations with the `-O1` compile flag it becomes:

```
   0x08048394 <+0>: ret
```

Since there's no need for a stack frame at all, `main` does nothing.

Comment: But i think return address isn't saved in the callee's frame. right ?

Comment: @user986424: I'm just stating how many bytes of memory on the stack it takes from calling to finish executing the function. That's why I worded it that way, count it how you like. That's not including everything else that goes on before you get to `main` either, or the .text section itself.